# How to extract text from element with attribute style="display:none;

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, display

**HTML of that part is:**

```
<div class="review-small-text">
 <span class="stars-rate">
    <span property="starsRating">
     <i class="fa fa-star-yellow fa-star"></i>  
     <i class="fa fa-star-yellow fa-star"></i>  
     <i class="fa fa-star-yellow fa-star"></i> 
     <i class="fa fa-star-yellow fa-star"></i>  
     <i class="fa fa-star-yellow fa-star"></i> 
  </span> 
</span>
<span property="reviewRating" typeof="Rating" style="display:none;">
    <span property="ratingValue">5</span> 
    <span property="bestRating">5</span>
    <span property="worstRating">0</span>
</span> 
<span property="itemReviewed" typeof="Service" class="">Liposuction</span> </div>
```

I'm trying to extract the **second span's** ratingValue of a particular review using selenium and i tried to extract that value by using this css selector:

```
'div.review-small-text>span:nth-of-type(2)>span:nth-of-type(1)'
```

but it is giving me an empty string.
**have also tried this one**

```
'div.review-small-text>span:nth-child(2)>span:nth-child(1)'
```

so I think the problem is not in the css-selector. Display none is creating an issue here. 
**Is there any possible way to extract that value?**

**Python source code that i have tried so far is:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
url = "myurlhere"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

all_reviews_listings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='tab_reviews']/div[@class='provider_all_Reviews']/div[@id='pnlReviews']/div")

for review in all_reviews_listings:
    review_rating = review.find_element_by_css_selector('div.review-small-text>span:nth-of-type(2)>span:nth-of-type(1)').text
    print("Review Rating: ", review_rating)
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract **5** from `property="ratingValue"`?

Comment: yes DebanjanB sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the css to get the ratingValue.

**Using JavaScript:**

```
review_rating = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector(".review-small-text > span[property='reviewRating'] > span[property='ratingValue']").textContent""")
```

**Without JavaScript:** Alternatively you can also do this.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".review-small-text > span:nth-child(2) > span[property='ratingValue']").get_attribute("textContent")
```

Comment: Though html is rendered but when in python i tried the same selector i get empty text

Comment: thanks alot sir its working now. 
I was trying .text which wasn't working. I was Forgetting to get text content instead.

Answer (score 0):

The ancestor  tag is having the attribute `style="display:none;`, so to extract all the **reviewRatings** you can use the following solution:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.review-small-text span[property='reviewRating'][typeof='Rating']"))
print([element.text for element in driver.find_elements_css_selector("div.review-small-text span[property='reviewRating'][typeof='Rating'] span")])
```